# How would I derive a function for the series of numbers: 1, 5, 13, 25, ...

Tags: integration

This series of numbers is called the [Centered Square Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centered_square_number).

I know that one formula for these numbers is:

$$
y = 2x^2 - 2x + 1
$$

So, I started here:

| n | y | y' | y'' |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |  |  |
| 2 | 5 | 4 |  |
| 3 | 13 | 8 | 4 |
| 4 | 25 | 12 | 4 |

So, I thought, $y'' = 4$.

Thus, $y' = 4x + C = 4x - 4$

So, then I said, $y = 2x^2 - 4x + C$

Eventually I brute forced it into the formula above.  I took the derivative and got $y' = 4x - 2$.  But that didn't fit my data.

Remembering that the derivative expresses $\frac{dy}{dx}$ I thought, "oh, the derivative at 2 is $\frac{y2 - y1}{2.5 - 1.5}$ and that matches my observation."

But, I can't figure out how to take all of these observations and deliberately figure out what the formula would be for the centered square numbers.

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't understand.  What's wrong with $a_n=2n^2+2n+1$?  Can't imagine anything simpler...   In any case, this is [A001844](https://oeis.org/A001844)

Comment: @lulu, there's nothing wrong with it.  I just had to brute force it because my math is weak.  I think other folks would be able to do it more deliberately without trial and error.  I'd like to know how.

Comment: Well..you need to start with *some* definition.  What definition are you starting with?

Comment: @lulu, I don't follow.  I started with the number series: 1, 5, 13, 25, ...

Comment: To elaborate:  if all you have is a list of, say, the first $100$ values in the sequence, there is no way to "know" what rule generated them (or if there even is a sensible rule).  Here, one certainly might have noticed that the second difference is constant ($=4$ as it happens) and that tells you that some quadratic fits the known sequence.  Then you could just match coefficients.

Comment: Specifically: given that $a_n=An^2+Bn+C$ for some constants $A,B,C$ we just remark that $a_0=1\implies C=1$ then $a_1=5$ tells us that $A+B+1=5$ and $a_2=13$ implies that $4A+2B+1=13$ and you can just solve that linear system.

Comment: Oops... it look like I ended up with lulu's answer in the comments.

Comment: @Doug  No worries!  Nothing proprietary about anything in the comments...they are just meant for quick, short lived hints.  Your answer is more general (+1).

Comment: Oh, I have 2 downvotes.  Is there a better community for asking basic math questions like this?

Comment: Why does $a_2 = 13$ imply that $4A + 2B + 1 = 13$?

Comment: I accidentally shifted your sequence.  I had $a_0=1, a_1=5, a_2=13$  which ends up giving $a_n=2n^2+2n+1$.  If you want to start at $n=1$ instead of $n=0$ you get what you wrote.  Either way is fine, of course.

Answer (score 1):

To derive the formula from scrtach ... you might start by assuming that the recurrence is of polynomial type.

General approach to solving polynomials recurrences would be to determine the order of the formula, and then apply undetermined coefficients.

Because $\nabla^2y(n)=4=\text{constant}$ for your sequence, this tells you that the formula will be quadratic.

So, your ansatz would be $y(n) = An^2+Bn+C$.  Now, set up a system of three equations in the variables $A,B,C$ using three base cases.  Then, solve this system for $A,B,C$.

$$1 = A*(1)^2+B*1+C$$
$$5 = A*(2)^2+B*2+C$$
$$13 = A*(3)^2+B*3+C$$

Comment: I did figure out that it was quadratic.  But, I don't understand how to set up and solve for A, B, and C.  Any chance you could elaborate on that process?

Comment: I added a system of three equations (for $n = 1,2,3$)

Comment: Ohhhhh, I get it.  And then I'd say something like $C = 1 - A - B$ and substitute that in.  Then do the same for B and solve for A?

Comment: Yes.  Although sort of standard way of solving systems by hand would be Gauss-elimination.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination